# How to pass object in url for controller?

Tags: java, spring

```
public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // all-args constructor
}
```

I move on `/start` and doing some logic in method  `redirect` inside `TestService`.

And I'm trying pass object in url, and redirect to another page, and show info about person, but faced with `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/start")
    public void stepOne(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        httpResponse = testService.redirect(httpResponse);
    }

    @GetMapping("/person")
    public String stepTwo(@RequestParam PersonDto personDto, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("result", personDto);
        return "person";
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    public HttpServletResponse redirect(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto("Alex", 27);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080" + "/person" +
                "?personDto=" + personDto;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Location", url);
        httpResponse.setStatus(302);
        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

I could pass object parts. Like this

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080" + "/person" +
                "?personDtoName=" + personDto.getName() +"&personDtoAge=" + personDto.getAge();
```

And getting parameters using `@RequestParam` without problems.

But could I pass the whole object in url?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your dto into a JSON object and have a try